# iOS AVPlayer not playing all remote files

Tags: ios, avfoundation, dropbox, avplayer, swiftydropbox

I'm using `SwiftyDropbox`'s `getTemporaryLink()` to play a video in an `AVPlayer`.  I have six test files, and they all work as expected, except 1.

The one that doesn't work is 41 MB in size (which I would not consider a large video file), the rest are < 22 MB.

I've read the `AVFoundation` and `SwiftDropbox` documentation many times and haven't been able to find anything on a maximum file size, though I wouldn't expect a maximum file size for streaming content. I would expect it to continuously play smaller chunks downloaded to memory.

My questions are:

1. Is there a file size limit on playing a remote URL in an `AVPlayer`?
2. If not, is there a certain way I need to use `AVPlayer` in order to stream these larger files?

I'm using the following code to start the `AVPlayer`:

```
self.previewPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: url)))
self.previewPlayer.play()
```

Thank-you!

Comment: Have you tried a different url?

Comment: Yes. Local files worked, and `http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4` remote video worked.

Comment: Use `let url = URL.init(string: urlStr)` instead of `URL(fileURLWithPath: url)` for remote content.

Comment: Thanks, @Adeel. Doing some reading, it appears that `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` is meant for use with the file system; however, it does work with remote paths as well.  Whether this is intended, I do not know.  I have also found that every other video file in the same Dropbox folder works as expected.  The one that doesn't work is larger (41 MB).  I'm now wondering if `AVPlayer` has a file size limit.

Comment: In light of that new discovery, I have rewritten the question.

Comment: There's no limitation on file size I'm sure. One of my applications streams movie files whose sizes are in excess of 1GB. To know what's exactly happening, you should do key value observation on `AVPlayerItem`. Specifically observe the value of `status` property.

Comment: Observing the status says it's "Ready to play", but is never actually played in the player.

Comment: can you share the entire code?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/iOS-getTemporaryLink-cannot-be-used-for-streaming/m-p/288674#M17675 ]

Answer (score 0):

You should observe the value of `status` property to know why the playerItem might have failed to play. Here's a small code snippet to start with:

1. Add observer

   ```
   let url = URL.init(string: "your url string")
   let item = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url!)
   item.addObserver(self,
                    forKeyPath: "status",
                    options: .new,
                    context: nil)
   ```
2. Check for the the error

   ```
   override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                              of object: Any?,
                              change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                              context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
       if let item = object as? AVPlayerItem, keyPath == "status" {
           if item.status == .failed {
               print(item.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: It doesn't fail. The status becomes `.readyToPlay`, but it doesn't actually start playing. Again, this only happens for one of my test videos.

Comment: The test videos are `.mp4` and `.mov` files.  The one that's not working is `.mov`, but another `.mov` is working.

Comment: Try one thing, download that file and play it from the application bundle.

Comment: Then the issue is with this file probably. Does it play in any other player?

Comment: Yeah, it plays in the browser and QuickTime no problem. It actually has an "MSG" watermark on it. I'm wondering if it has a copyright on it that prevents AVPlayer from playing it?